# Как защитить WEB API от не санкционированных запросов через алгоритмы? ​

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, алгоритм, node.js

Хочется хоть как-нибудь защитить веб приложение от накруток. Для этого у меня возникла идея организовать некий алгоритм генерации случайной строки, которую бы понимали обе стороны: сервер и браузер.

Что-то вроде капчи, но без участия пользователя. Например, при открытии страницы сервер генерирует строку и записывает его клиенту в куку, а себе кладет в сессию. Клиенту в какой-то момент нужно общаться с сервером и он хочет отправить Ajax запрос. Перед этим он берет эту строку, который записал ему сервер и выполняет определенные манипуляции, например, считает количество букв, чисел, как-то преобразовывает, смешивает, использует математические функции, хэширует и т.д. В результате, кладет эту новую сгенерированную на основе старой строку и отправляет серверу. Сервер производит те же операции, у него должно получиться такая же строка, которую он получил от клиента. Если получается, то всё ok. Если нет, то предполагаем, что накрутка.

Это решение можно масштабировать, например, задать 10 разных алгоритмов и сервер будет отправлять по какому именно будем работать дальше. Также можно записывать в куку что-то вроде соли и дополнительно использовать это значение для генерации нужного нам ключа. Затем сжать код через google closure compiler или подобные сервис для того, чтобы код клиента труднее читался. Т.е. цель максимально запутать злоумышленника.

Понимаю, что если сильно нужно будет разобраться в этих алгоритмах, то наверное, умные люди разберутся. Ведь нет 100% защиты от накруток, также как и от любых замков, все ломается, вопрос лишь времени. Но, тут защита «от дурака». Т.е. если злоумышленник будет знать, что у вас нет дома дверного замка на входной двери, то обязательно зайдет в ваше отсутствие. Если будет знать, что у вас хороший замок, просто связываться не будет.

Может быть у кого-то есть практика в подобном. Есть алгоритмы. Или какие-то ссылки, буду очень рад.
Спасибо!
​

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону basic-авторизации.

Comment: а что значит накрутка?

Comment: Если хэш, то (Время действия запроса + соль + разные значения). Сервер разбирает запрос, смотрит прошло ли время, если прошло, то запрос неверный.

Comment: @n.osennij это циклическая отправка запроса с одними и теми же параметрами от одного и того же пользователя.

Comment: @user3741469, Не совсем понимаю, какое время должно пройти?

Comment: Ммм... а почему нельзя сделать тогда просто проверку на количество запросов в секунду, минуты, 10 секунд - как угодно. Например, не более 5 запросов за 30 секунд от пользователя. Ну и ещё, если api с авторизацией, вы же обмениваетесь токеном (Барьер, тот же,например). Можно просто менять этот токен при каждом логине пользователя. Тогда и автовыход будет на других устройствах (только с одного одновременно можно работать), и защита какая-никакая.

Comment: Можно состыковать время клиента с сервером. То есть, у клиента обязательно должно быть выставлен правильное время. Когда передаем запрос с клиента - берем время timestamp(в секундах), прибавляем какое время будет действовать запрос (допустим 1 сек). Соответственно, хэш = время+timestamp + соль + параметры. Сервер проверяет время у себя, и если это время больше, чем в запросе, тогда запрос невалидный. И каждый хэш будет разный, отправить его повторно нельзя будет, ибо время истечет. А вообще, вот сказали про ограничение запросов, хорошая мысль, если у Вас они повторяются.

Comment: @n.osennij А если гость? И допустим на сервере реализован механизм подсчета количества запросов по uid. Но что мешает написать простое CURL скрипт с нужными заголовками плюс токенами от сервера? Я бы чистил куки при каждом блоке, чтобы получить новые uid и все равно бы накручивал. даже, если бы сервер меня блокировал по ip,  я бы мог легко изменить с помощью Tor. А используя логику, злоумышленник должен будет понять, как это работает и что ему нужно отправить, чтобы сервер не отверг его запрос.

Comment: @user3741469 А если. как вы сказали у клиента время не правильное.. Или к примеру он отошел от компьютера на час, потом опять решил поработать. Всё будет блочить. Это не удобно ставить пользователя во временные рамки. Тем более все это также обходится с помощью CURLa.